# ssh to multiple hosts and run a command

Tags: ssh, shell-script

How do I ssh into multiple hosts (e.g host1, host2, host3, etc) and cat `/etc/fstab` to generate `report.txt`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can `ssh hostname command` and redirect the output to your report.txt

The following script to get this report from all of your hosts. servername.dat contains all the host names.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 SERVERLIST=servername.dat
 ICMD='cat /etc/fstab'
 while read SERVERNAME
 do
    ssh -n $SERVERNAME $ICMD > $SERVERNAME_report.txt
 done < "$SERVERLIST"
```

Comment: you might want to use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: Yes, if required append

Answer (score 6):

You can do that like that:

```
for i in username1@host1 username@host2; do ssh $i cat /etc/fstab >> report.txt; done
```

Provided that you have ssh public key authentication set on your hosts (host1 & host2), if not you will be prompted for the password for each host.