# SSH to multiple hosts in file and run command fails - only goes to the first host

Tags: ssh

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVERLIST=hosts
ICMD='cat /etc/redhat-release'
while read SERVERNAME
do
   ssh $SERVERNAME $ICMD
done < "$SERVERLIST"
```

With `hosts` just like:

```
hostname
hostname
hostname
```

When I run the script `./run.sh` it only goes to a single host and stops. Why is it not reading the entire host list?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #89: I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ssh pre-reads stdin on the assumption that the remote job will want some data, and it makes for a faster start-up. So the first job eats the rest of your hosts list.

You can prevent this happening either using the `ssh -n` option, or by redirecting like `ssh < /dev/null`. Being a belt-and-braces man, I do both: `ssh -n < /dev/null <other ssh options>`.

If you really want the remote job to read something from the local system, you need to pipe it, or here-doc it, for each iteration. Even with `for <host>`, ssh will read an indeterminate amount of data from stdin for each host start-up.

I would always ping a remote host to get status before ssh to it. IIRC, `ping -W` has a hard timeout option, while `ssh` can hang in DNS or while connecting for 90+ seconds, for an unknown or dead host.

Comment: That makes sense! It explains why the [original answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80204/8965) OP referenced (in my since-deleted incorrect assumption) works but this one doesn't.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco The second answer in that thread has the same fault anyway -- I was not certain which was being cited.

Comment: Another trick is to use a separate file-descriptor in the `3<servers` and `read -u 3`, though this isnt POSIX for read

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `pdsh` for this, it allows running a command in parallel on multiple hosts.

```
pdsh -w ^hostlist.txt -R ssh "cat /etc/redhat-release"
```

`^` defines a file with the list of hostnames, alternatively a comma separated list could be used:

```
pdsh -w host1,host2,host3,... -R ssh "cat /etc/redhat-release"
```

A result would look like:

```
pdsh, -w raspi,raspi.local,192.168.0.3,localhost,127.0.0.1 -R ssh "cat /etc/issue"

raspi: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
raspi: 
raspi.local: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
raspi.local: 
192.168.0.3: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
192.168.0.3: 
localhost: Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
localhost: 
127.0.0.1: Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
127.0.0.1:
```